# vue - integrate jquery plugin with v-if

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to integrate the jsTree plugin in my vue code.
https://www.jstree.com/

This is a simplified version of my problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/hqcmu8pt/7/

```
<div id="app">
  Tree is gone after one toggle.
  <button type="button" @click="show= !show">
   toggle tree
  </button>

  <div v-if="show">
    Tree: <br>
    <div id="tree"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to lazy initialize the tree, only once, when the user toggle the tree visibility. So a watcher seems fine for that.
The issue is that after the first time the tree is created in the watcher handler, in the next toggle the tree is completely destroyed and never go back to the DOM.

How can I make vue understand my DOM change?
I can't use `v-show` with `mounted` because that won't give me a lazy load (my actual tree uses ajax).
`<keep-alive>` didn't work as well.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why v-show won't give you lazy load? Can't you check if the ajax request was sent or not, before sending a request? This line: `if (!newValue || this.tree) return` is the reason your tree only renders once. `this.tree` evaluates to true after the first render, so your tree is never rebuilt in the watcher.

Comment: But as i've said, I want to init the tree only once. After the watcher has fired, the tree is in the DOM, after v-if toggle, it's gone

Comment: As a consequence of using `v-if`, you have to init the tree every time you toggle. You should still be able to lazy load with `v-show`, unless you post an example of why `v-show` doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't you use a vue library. There are a couple for this.